# change xml namespace (VB)

Tags: .net, vb.net, xml-namespaces

I am trying to create an XML document. 
I've successfully created the document however I can't seem to figure out how to change the default xmlns to something else.
here is my Code

```
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1  

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter("product.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        writer.WriteStartDocument(True)
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        writer.Indentation = 2
        writer.WriteStartElement("_-SAPMP_-PPCC2PRETT01")
        writer.WriteStartElement("IDOCBEGIN", 1)
        createNode("00B-021-5088", "BRL1", "KG", "1000", writer)
        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteEndDocument()
        writer.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub createNode(ByVal pID As String, ByVal pName As String, ByVal pName2 As String, ByVal pPrice As String, ByVal writer As XmlTextWriter)
        writer.WriteStartElement("E1BP_PP_TIMETICKET", "E1BP_PP_TIMETICKET")
        writer.WriteStartElement("ORDERID")
        writer.WriteString(pID)
        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteStartElement("PLANT")
        writer.WriteString(pName)
        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteStartElement("CONF_QUAN_UNIT")
        writer.WriteString(pName2)
        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteStartElement("YIELD")
        writer.WriteString(pPrice)
        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteEndElement()
    End Sub

End Class
```

### This results in the following XML file:

[image: not expected]

### What I want it to look like is:

[image: expected]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of `WriteStartElement` is the namespace, not attributes.  You should use `WriteAttributeString` to write out the attributes for an element.  So, a couple of changes should get you what you want:

```vb
'...
writer.WriteStartElement("IDOC")
writer.WriteAttributeString("BEGIN", "1")
'...
writer.WriteStartElement("E1BP_PP_TIMETICKET")
writer.WriteAttributeString("SEGMENT", "E1BP_PP_TIMETICKET")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, all you'd need to do is add this line:

```
writer.Namespaces = false;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.namespaces(v=vs.110).aspx